# How to easily dissect a link with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, split

How would I go about dissecting a link/href with Javascript or JQuery?

I can use split to split some of the variables up, but I was wondering if there is an easier way to go about this, for example...

www.url.com/dir/page?setting&var1=value1

What would be the easiest way to get dir, page, and setting.

P.S.  It would be nice to always select the last directory, so using a standard split won't always work if there are multiple directories.

Comment: *"so using a standard split won't always work if there are multiple directories"* What are you talking about?

Comment: Why do you want to get setting, but not var1? Not sure yet what you're really asking for. Maybe show us your code using `split`, and an example where it fails.

Comment: http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/

Comment: split + regex :) or as mentioned just use URI.js

Comment: Did you try `URL.split(/[/?]/)` ?? Test it: http://jsfiddle.net/Mk4HV/1/

Comment: I meant multiple directories as in, if it were url.com/dir1/dir2/page?setting, I wouldn't want it returning dir1 instead of dir2.  So if I were using a normal split and counting the outputs, it wouldn't work as well because the URLs won't always be the same.

Comment: URL.split seems to work well, but I think it will fail me when I use a secondary directory as everything will shift over one key.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend James Padolsey's URL parser -- it's a simple JS function that will give you any part of the URL (host, querystring, path, etc..)

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/parsing-urls-with-the-dom/

Comment: This looks like a good solution, I will have to tweak it to my needs but definitely a start.  Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

[parseUri](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri) seems to do exactly what you're asking for, in terms of splitting the url into it's component parts.